# i dont know what error in my url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite my url using the htaccess file, but it does not work.  I have enabled mod_rewrite and Allow Access, but still it does not work for local and online.  What is wrong with my rewrite code?

I want to rewrite this url

> http://example.com/post/post.php?pid=104

like this

> http://example.com/post/post-pid-104.htm

This is my htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule post-pid-(.*)\.htm$ post.php?pid=$1
```

Comment: What is your target URI? What should be transposed into what?

Comment: my target is change ugly url to friendly url

Comment: I tried your config. It works on my server. I can access _post.php?pid=14_ by typing _post-pid-14.htm_

Comment: ok. i need to contact my server company for clear this ... thank you for you try.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `RewriteRule post.php?pid=(.*)$ post-pid-$1.htm$`

Comment: thanks to your replay but still does not show like that on online

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite lines are fine, it looks like it's a problem with your server configuration.
You can test your rewrite rules with this: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/